# How to get Icon value that is not a URL from JSON object in Ionic 3

Tags: json, ionic3, icons

I am trying to retrieve an icon from a JSON object using Ionic 3 and weather.org API.
The JSON structure is below:

[image]

The JSON object is retuned as expected and all other fields are accessible. When I attempt to reference the icon I get a 'Resource Not Found':
This is the call in my HTML file where weatherToday is the JSON object:

```
{{weatherToday?.weather[0]?.icon}}
```

When making other API calls the image is represented by a url:

[image]

Which is retrievable:

```
this.weatherImage = this.weatherToday.weather[0].main;
```

So my question how do I retrieve the Icon value for the Icon key in the first JOSN object?

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful to others using the openweathermap.org API, After looking further into the [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions) there is a reference to a preceding URL that needs to be prepended to the value of the Icon key returned from the JSON object: [http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{Icon_Value}.png](http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/%7BIcon_Value%7D.png)